# Pass data into values parameter using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, node-postgres

Currently, what I want to do is pass the value that I received into the values constant. But it won't accept it and I am not sure how to workaround with it since nothing works from what I searched on. The data is all there except that it wont read it.

```
app.patch(`/users/edit/3`, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

const text = 'UPDATE users(username, email, first_name, last_name, imageInput) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) WHERE user_id=3'
const values = [`${req.body.username}`, `${req.body.email}`, `${req.body.first_name}`, `${req.body.last_name}`, `${req.body.imageInput}`]
  
  db.query(text, values)
       .then(() => {
        console.log("success!");
        // success;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Whats the output of `console.log(values)` ?? Also why this `[\`${req.body.username}\`, ...]` when you can simply do this `[req.body.username,...]` ??

Comment: Just realized that this `UPDATE users(username, email, first_name, last_name, imageInput) VALUES` doesn't seem to be correct syntax of UPDATE. It should be more like `UPDATE users SET (username, ...) = ($1,...)`

Comment: That worked for me! Thank you very much! @Molda